# Anti windup on PidController

Tags: drake

I'm using PidController in a drake project and I need of an anti windup control to limit the integral term growth. I was examine the PidController documentation,

https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1controllers_1_1_pid_controller.html

but I cannot find functions or parameters related to this limit.
It is correct or i missed something in the documentation?

What's the smartest way to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree; the current `PidController` implementation does not provide those features. It would not be too hard to implement this (by modifying the current `PidController` interface in C++, or providing a similar implementation in pydrake). And we would welcome a contribution like this if you wanted to make it.

For bonus points, the class should really declare witness events when the "clamp" turns on/off, so that error-controlled integrators get to know about this discontinuity.

Comment: and for the bonus point. I'd like to contribute to the project. I'll work on a local fork it and I'll send a pull request.